# What is contextual Knowledge?

Tags: computer-vision, machine-learning

Contextual knowledge (CK) is used in some AI application, Can someone give me a concrete definition of this term.

I am working on ontologies( a set of concepts and relationships among them) and computer vision. I basically aim at integrating knowledge (ontologies) and visual features extracted from images to leverage machine vision techniques.  I crossed one of the scientific research paper and I encountered the term "Contextual Knowledge" and they give no explicit or even abstract description of it and that makes me wonder about it. Intuitively, I believe, it is used in knowledge representation or knowledge based construction and it must have something to do with databases... But unfortunately, I couldnt find the concrete and informative information about it or even its use in different disciplines

Comment: Hello! Welcome to DSP. We'll be glad to help, but could you give us some context? Where did you come across the term CK? Is there a definition you don't understand from your class or textbook, or just self-learning? Why is this concept even interesting for you (and then, consequently, for us?)

Comment: You should edit your question (you're allowed to do that to your own questions) with all the extra information. In addition to making your question better, an edit also bums the question up and makes it more visible to other people.

Comment: I will update it

Comment: What make you think this has anything to do with signal processing?